# spring batch dynamic query to itemreader

Tags: spring, spring-batch

```
<bean id="PagingItemReaderSANDOS"
class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader"
scope="step">
```

always required a data source and a query provider

but i have a scenario where i have to create a query  for ItemReader by  using some db configuration how to archive this .

I have to make the batch configuration database driven not from xml cause xml required a server restart how to avoid that .  is there any way i can archive both like query will be formed by java program and push it to  itemreader with out restart of server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the @PostConstruct phase you should be able to get access to the underlying datasource if your itemreader is @StepScope. There you can set also the desired query for the reader.

I just dont know how transaction handling is playing here.

Another possibility would be to add another step in front of your chunk step which will prepare the query in the correct context. This can then be prepared in the itemreader.

Comment: can you suggest some example link regarding this @martin frey